# best and fast solution for internationalization applications?

Tags: php, gettext

i just finished my script and now i want to translate this code to another language like english.now i am looking for best and fastest way to achieve that.many people talk about php_gettext but in php.net some body said:

> The GNU gettext library works on a per-process, not per-thread basis.
>   This means that in a multi-user setting such as the Apache web server
>   it will only work with a prefork MPM (i.e. one process per user).
>   Worker and other threaded MPMs will not work.
>
> In addition, many users control GNU gettext by setting system
>   environment variables such as LANG. This is not a good solution for a
>   web server environment due to an obvious race condition.

and for array,i think load such a big array and use just 7 or 8 line of that in one page is wasting resources.but i know arrays are fast but arrays is not flexible enough.

what you think is the best solution and ill be grateful if you refrence the extinsion or somewere to learn that solution.

2-it was a question for me what facebook use for translation?is facebook use zend framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/), which is sometimes better choice than native implementation in PHP.